# SQL group by and select with condition in each column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select a table, group by it into a subset and keep only 'Y' values of each column within each group.

And replace the value 'Y' with the first column ID value.

my table like this

```
ID      Date        MachineNo Operator1 Operator2 Operator3 Operator4 Reporter1 Reporter2 Reporter3 Reporter4
A57611  2019-01-02   5515         Y        N          N          N        N         N         Y         N
D75451  2019-01-02   5515         N        Y          N          N        N         Y         N         N
E10758  2019-01-02   5515         N        N          Y          N        Y         N         N         N
E41020  2019-01-02   5515         N        N          N          Y        N         N         N         Y
...
F20124  2019-01-02   5405         Y        N          N          N        N         N         Y         N
A45687  2019-01-02   5405         N        N          Y          N        N         Y         N         N
B22511  2019-01-02   5405         N        Y          N          N        Y         N         N         N
C45451  2019-01-02   5405         N        N          N          Y        N         N         N         Y
...
```

And I want to select a table like this:
Group by Date and MachineNo

Replace 'Y' with ID of each row and each group combines into one row

```
  Date      MachineNo Operator1 Operator2 Operator3 Operator4 Reporter1 Reporter2 Reporter3 Reporter4
2019-01-02    5515      A57611    D75451    E10758    E41020    E10758    D75451   A57611    E41020
2019-01-02    5405      F20124    B22511    A45687    C45451    B22511    A45687   F20124    C45451
...
```

The method that I can imagine now is "join" multiple times, but I am wondering is there any better way to do it.

Note: 'Y' only appears once in each group on operator and reporter columns.

Comment: Can you include the query you already tried?

Comment: @IvanLin . . . What do you mean by "first id"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "first" unless a column has that information.  In addition, your sample data has no examples of duplicates where "first" would be relevant.

Comment: @Gamopo thank you, I think the forpas answer can help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry for the confuse, I just want to say the ID column which is the first column of my table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation if you `group by date, machineno`:

```
select date, machineno,
  max(case when operator1 = 'Y' then ID end) operator1,
  ...........................................................
  max(case when reporter1 = 'Y' then ID end) reporter1,
  ...........................................................
from tablename
group by date, machineno
```